# Confirm dialog pops up twice using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, dialog

I'm adding a button that closes an app I'm developing using Apache Cordova a.k.a Phonegap, android SDK and Jquery Mobile but instead of closing the app immediately I wanted the app to show a confirmation dialog box asking the users if they are sure they want to leave the app... To achieve that I added This plugin which provides access to some native dialog UI elements by issuing the following: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs.

So in this case I want to use the following method: navigator.notification.confirm

The current problem I am having is that when I click on the Close App Buttom the confirmation dialog pops up twice and I can´t figure out why:

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function exitFromApp() {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            '¿Are you sure you want to leave the App?',
            onConfirm,
            'App Name',
            'Yes, No'
            );
    }

    function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
        if (buttonIndex === 1){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }

    }   

</script>
```

HTML:

Link to fire the confirmation dialog:

```
<a href="#" onclick="exitFromApp()">Close Application</a>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you try using event `touchend` instead of `onclick` and change `exitFromApp()` to `exitFromApp(event)` and add the statement at the start of the `exitFromApp(event)` function `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your guidance on this. Can you please enlighten me on how to implement this in the code above? I have never used touchend event before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile and `onclick` has some issues. I faced it but can't explain why.

I will suggest the following way.

Give id to the link

```
<a href="#" id="btn_close">Close Application</a>

$(document).on('click', "#btn_close",function () {

      exitFromApp();

});
```